# how to send XML file to web server using wget command from unix shell script

Tags: unix, shell, webserver, wget, xml

I am trying to send an xml file to webserver using wget command in unix as below

wget --post-file xyz.xml http://

i am getting 400 bad request error,please help me

Comment: Could you post the name of the webserver? Maybe test it with "wget --post-file xyz.xml http://httpbin.org/anything" first, it might be server side problem, command looks OK. That address is a function on a testing server, will return anything you POST to it.

Comment: http://<serverip>:port#/api/

Comment: I meant actual address of the server, not the scheme. That '#' doesn't look right, though. 400 often means impossible address, if you really post it like this, try omitting it. Also check server limits (max file size, allowed filename characters etc.), perhaps your connection - ISPs, employers and cheap network gear can do ugly things to unencrypted content. If you're behind proxy, try it from elsewhere, if not, use https://whatismyipaddress.com/proxy-check to double-check.

Answer (score 0):

This is an example of POST to a Webservice to register an IP in an internal Microsoft DNS.

```
wget --post-file=myxml.xml --header="Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8" --header="SOAPAction: \"http://tempuri.org/IServiziXXX/AddRecordPassLocal\"" http://servizixxx.mydomain.local:810/ServiziXXX.svc
```

And this is the file **myxml.xml**

`<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
  <SOAP-ENV:Envelope xmlns:SOAP-ENV="http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/" 
 xmlns:ns1="http://tempuri.org/">
    <SOAP-ENV:Body>
      <ns1:AddRecordPassLocal><ns1:domain>stage.local</ns1:domain><ns1:recordName>my-server-name</ns1:recordName><ns1:ipDestination>192.168.1.1</ns1:ipDestination></ns1:AddRecordPassLocal>
    </SOAP-ENV:Body>
  </SOAP-ENV:Envelope>`